# App Script - Run function for Rows that have timestamp bigger than last function run

Tags: javascript

I have a sheet of 2000 rows and 60 columns that is edided by multiple users constantly. I have to sync this sheets every 10 Minutes to another sheet so I wrote the following script to do so.

```
// Sync Sheet 
// Monday through Friday between 9am and 6pm

function TriggerSync() {

    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();
    var hrs = date.getHours();

    if ((day >= 1) && (day <= 5) && (hrs >= 9) && (hrs <= 18)) {


        // Sync  
        var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var srcSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Overview");

        //destination spreadsheet (Intermediate)
        var destinationSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID');
        var destSheet = destinationSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("intermediate");

        //get Data from Souce Sheet
        var values = srcSheet.getRange(5, 2, 2000, 60).getValues();

        //dump 
        destSheet.getRange(2, 3, 2000, 60).setValues(values);

    }
}
```

This works fine but as you can imagine copying all this data, regardless of whether it has been changed since the last sync or not, takes a lot of time and results in function timeouts. I now am planning to write a timestamp in column 62 and then only sync the rows with a timestamp bigger than the last function run.

But here I am at a loss where to start. Appreciate any help on how to start.

Thanks in advance